# Ionic scope value isn't updated navigate between $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaBOwv

```
.controller('CheckinCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$root.showRight = true;

})

.controller('AttendeesCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.$root.showRight = false;
  alert($scope.$root.showRight)
});
```

I use ng-show to show hide the right button on menu. But when I try it vice-versa I found that the value of the scope isn't updating due to cache. I dislike to use `cache:false` in the state because it's such a bad experience for the user. But how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

On entering a new view, `$ionicView.enter` will be broadcast to $scope, that's the place to put your code, if you want your code to be executed every time user enters the view.

Change your code to

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('eventmenu', {
      url: "/event",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/event-menu.html"
    })
    .state('eventmenu.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.checkin', {
      url: "/check-in",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/check-in.html",
          controller: "CheckinCtrl"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.attendees', {
      url: "/attendees",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/attendees.html",
          controller: "AttendeesCtrl"
        }
      }
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event/home");
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.$root.showRight = true;

  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
})

.controller('CheckinCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter",function(){

    $scope.$root.showRight = true;
  });

})

.controller('AttendeesCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter",function(){

    $scope.$root.showRight = false;
  });
  // alert($scope.$root.showRight)
});
```

And it should work

Comment: `$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter",function(){

    $scope.$root.showRight = false;
  });` this alone will work?

Comment: yes just replace ```$scope.$root.showRight = false;``` with ```$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter",function(){ $scope.$root.showRight = false; });``` sorry for being so verbose

Comment: it actually solved the problem! Thanks! but imagine what if I have 10 pages / controller? I have to repeat that in the beginning of every controller?

Comment: Ionic uses ```ui-router```. By default, every controller is initialized only once, when the user first enters the view associated with the controller. As a result, the code in the controller closure will only be run once, when the controller is initialized. If you want the code to run whenever the user enters the view, you have to put it in the ```$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", callback)``` callback closure. It's actually a good thing, you can freely choose what code to run only once, and what to run every time the user enters the view.

Comment: This is actually a caching mechanism, you may refer to http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Comment: If you don't want to use ```$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", callback)``` for all the controllers, an alternative is to disable caching, with ```$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);``` in angular.config, you may find out more at Ionic's official docs. (The link I posted just now, section ```Disable cache globally```)

Comment: Ya I know it's caching issue, I want to keep the caching.

Comment: By using ng-show, and ionicView.enter, I got small flick, means It will show a while then hide. Hmm.. any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: It shouldn't, I haven't noticed any flick.. Modified code pen here: https://codepen.io/KevinWang15/pen/oxMRdz  Have you added anything new to your project? like ```ng-animate``` ? You may try ```$ionicView.beforeEnter``` instead of ```$ionicView.enter``` and see whether it solves the problem for you.

Comment: I used beforeEnter instead of enter, it solved the issue! thanks for letting me know $ionicView!